# Grails urls mapping

Tags: grails

what the urls mapping processing order for the grails framework

- "/$object/$id/$collection"
- "/$object/$id/bar/list"
- "/foo/$id/bar/list"

Which one will execute first. I'm getting unexpected behavior where the generic mapping seems to execute first

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achieve ?

**/$object/$id/bar/list** maps **/foo/$id/bar/list** to.
But if you want any custom behavior for **foo** you can set constrainst for first mapping, e.g.:

```
/$object/$id/bar/list {
controller = "bar"
    action = "list"
    constraints {
      object(matches: /.*[^fo].*/)
    }
}

"/foo/$id/bar/list"
```

Regexp is not ideal but it shows basic principles

Answer (score 0):

i believe the order will be

```
/foo/$id/bar/list          // 1 value to calc
/$object/$id/bar/list      // 2 value(s) to calc
/$object/$id/$collection   // all unknown values
```

[grails documentation](http://www.grails.org/URL%20mapping) states the strongest will take precedent, meaning whatever does not have to be calculated at runtime.